# Validate how session expiration is done

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Reading the docs, I came to the following assumption. Can someone please validate if it is correct or not? thanks

If the heartbeat is set to 10 seconds, then the client sends 1 heartbeat every 10 seconds.

Then there are two conditions:

1. If `isCloseIdleSessions() == false`, then if after `3x10 = 30` seconds there's no user interaction, the session is NOT killed. It would be killed in 30 seconds if there's no UI visible on the browser.
2. If on the other hand `isCloseIdleSessions() == true`, then after `3x10 = 30` seconds there's no user interaction while the UI is visible the session is killed. The session is killed too if no UI is visible on the browser.

Comment: 2. is not entirely true. If closeIdleSessions == true, then session is marked to be killed after session timeout, not based on heart beats.

Comment: Hi Tatu,how do you set this 'session-timeout' ?

Comment: when I set the server.servlet.session.timeout , then the session is actually killed by Tomcat and the application is not being directed to the setSessionExpiredURL.If I don't set server.servlet.session.timeou, then the UI Vaadin session never expires! either with closeIdleSessions true or not

Comment: "when I set the server.servlet.session.timeout  , then the session is actually killed by Tomcat ... .If I don't set server.servlet.session.timeou, then the UI Vaadin session never expires! either with closeIdleSessions true or not" The both are correct behaviors.

Comment: "setSessionExpiredURL", I have this usually null, the default. Then my application jumps to login screen, as my login configuration is made in a way that if the user is not logged in, it forwards to login. I would say that it is the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: So let me get that straight.When closeidlesessions is true then the heartbeats are ignored ? and the timeout happens only when servlet.session.timeout is exceeded?